# Any freeware tools to set LAA after the fact?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, memory

I have done some digging and poking and have come up short.  I am looking for a freeware tool that I can give to my users to set Large Address Aware after I have given my application.

Background:
I work on a piece of software that has ~500 users.  A small number (maybe 25?) of these users are running into memory problems when doing multiple large searches.  The application is 32bit and is being run on everything from Win XP machines with 2 gigs of ram (if they are lucky) to users who are running 64bit Windows 7 with 4+ gigs of ram.

My team considered setting LAA after compile using the post build events, but a few of the websites I came across said there could be problems on older systems.  If this information is wrong though and it would work with the old (small amount of ram) machines I wouldn't need the tool.

Thanks all.

Comment: I up voted back out of the negative range. Your question may be mistagged but it is still valid. I can't think of appropriate tags.

Comment: Don't "pity upvote". The question shows no research effort and claims rumors without sources.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize it was proper overflow etiquette to submit my search history.  The problem I was running into was a lot of information from the mid 2000's. I am unaware what has changed and honestly it is easier to ask people who have more knowledge to make sure I am not over looking anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick google search turned up this, http://www.techpowerup.com/forums/showthread.php?t=112556.[image]

Answer (score 4):

Personally I like CFF Explorer. It can mark programs LAA as well as a ton of other features.

http://www.ntcore.com/exsuite.php

Comment: Thanks for this.  It is more than I want to give the end users but it is something I think I will use for myself :)